# Sum member sizes of a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array,

```
a=cell(2,1); 
a{1,1}=[1 2 3];
a{2,1}=[4 5];
```

I need to calculate the sum of lengths of fields of `a`, i.e. the answer should be `3+2=5`. This can be done using `for` loop,

```
sum=0;
for i=1:size(a,1)
    sum = sum + size(a{i},2); 
end
```

But, I need one line command without loops. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a one-liner, use `cellfun`

```
sum(cellfun(@length,a))
```

`cellfun` applies the command `length` to each element of `a`, then `sum` adds the output.

Comment: thanks dude! too bad I can't select your answer too as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
length( [ a{:} ] )
```

Comment: Clever! Note this will work only as long as the elements of `a` contain row-vectors.

Comment: Oh, only just noticed it now. Thanks for that comment, btw!